# Speed up PCI SATA controller boot

Tags: boot, bios, sata

I have a Conceptronic [CSATA600EXI V1](http://www.conceptronic.net/download_list.php?stype=3&productid=30), and that thing is REALLY good, but it takes around 10-15 seconds in the BIOS.

I've tried to change the connection to only 1 internal SATA and 1 eSATA, but there is no change.

I didn't tried to remove the jumpers from the unused connection.

Is there any way to speed up the boot? Or reduce the time it takes to search for drives?
Also, is it safe to remove the jumpers from the unused connection as an attempt to force the controller to ignore that unused port?

Comment: It takes 10-15 to cold boot into an OS or do you mean something else?  What OS are you using?

Comment: I mean that the controller's BIOS takes 10-15 seconds to detect the drives. It actually takes 25 seconds to get to the Windows loading screen, and 10 to get to the desktop, fully loaded. And I'm using Windows 8.1, but that doesn't matter. It could even be MS-DOS.